# How can I correctly configure this WSO2 Scheduled Task to perform a simple REST service call?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** (I am using it under EI 6) and I have the following problem. I have to create a simple scheduled taks that every 5 seconds perform a call to a **REST service** like this:

```
http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.HHH:8280/info/country/senegal
```

So following the official documentation I created a scheduled task into my ESB project, it contains this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="TestTask" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger count="5" interval="5"/>
</task>
```

that I think means: **"for 5 times perform an operation every 5 seconds"**.

Ok but I can't understand how to specify how to call the previous REST WS.

I found this link that contains information about how to **"Injecting messages to RESTful Endpoints"**:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks

But I am not understanding what exactly I have to do to set this scheduled call.

Reading on this documentation it says that:

> In order to use the Message Injector to inject a message to a RESTful
>   endpint, we can specify the injector with the required payload and
>   inject the message to sequence or proxy service as defined above. The
>   sample below shows a RESTful message injection through a ProxyService.

I think that this **Message Injector** is the scheduled taks component that perform the call to my REST endpoint (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion, I am absolutly not sure of it). What is the mentioned **ProxyService** and what it is used for? It seems to me the REST web service configuration container. Something that it is executed to perform my call.

But I have so many doubts...can you help me to perform my simple call to my REST WS?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document page you've linked check the part *Injecting the message to a named sequence or proxy service*. So you can build a simple proxy service or a sequence to call your service endpoint and the task would invoke the sequence or proxy with the defined message